# Sort in forward_lists using BigO notation?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, big-o

Basically, anyone knows, what should be the Big-O notation (needed for the assignment) for the `sort()` function of the new C++11 `forward_list` class?

Just a small working example of it: reading from a file:

```
std::forward_list<string> words3;
ifstream songs;
songs.open ("songs.txt");
string line;

while (songs){
    getline (songs, line);
    words3.push_front(line);
}
words3.sort();
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list/sort) is good for looking up these kinds of things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the C++11 standard §23.3.4.6/23.

> *Complexity:* Approximately *N* log *N* comparisons, where *N* is `distance(begin(), end())`.

Comment: I think it's quite annoying that the text is only visible when hovering.

Comment: @Nicol: So what? Students aren't smart enough to use their mouse these days?